# Is the word "claim" offensive?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, politeness

If I say this guy claims that something is true.

Would he be offended by that? Should I use: asserts, beleives? instead.

Comment: It depends on what "something" is. Basically, would the guy be offended if he is wrong? The actual word probably does not matter as much. Wrong is wrong.

Comment: What I mean is that, doesn't the word claim hold a meaning that I don't believe that he has evidences supporting it. Does it hold a meaning of disrespect of his belief?(that's how I understand it)

Comment: Like many questions about word usage, it depends on context. What is the context?

Comment: @CarSmack - True. Plus, in this case, I think _tone_ can be just as important as _context_. Take, for example, "He claims that the repair will cost us €3000," versus, "He ***claims*** that the repair will cost us €3000." When the word _claim_ is emphasized, it may more strongly suggest the speaker is questioning the integrity of the company quoting the price of the repair.

Comment: If you are concerned, just use *asserts*; it is the most neutral of the three.

Comment: Or if you are *really* concerned, just use "says." But, tone and context can make *even* "says" offensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the context and how you say it. *Claim* in and of itself is not a rude word, but it does imply doubt. When you point out to someone that they're *claiming* something, you're effectively saying *you know that might be false, right?* Some people don't like being questioned, and sometimes questioning is rude.

Is the person making the claim completely confident that they're right? Are they hostile towards criticism or questioning? Is what they said generally accepted as correct? If so, then it's more likely, but not assured, that saying *claim* will be taken rudely.

Your stress and pronunciation will play a large role as well. If you place a lot of emphasis on *claim* and drop your tone as you say it, you will come across as rude, but this is true for a lot words.

*Belief* carries about the same weight and subtext as claim to most people, and so it's roughly equally likely to be taken as rude (and the same caveats about delivery and context apply). *Assert* is more formal, so it's less likely (but still possible) to come across as rude when using it, because formality inherently conveys a higher degree of politeness than casual speech.

Some examples:

> According to our new algorithm, we can solve this graph coloring problem in [O(n^39) time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).
>   So you claim that [P = NP](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP)?

Not rude. This is a technical discussion among computer science researchers, and someone has just said something extraordinary and revolutionary. Skepticism is both appropriate and expected.

> My daughter is so beautiful!
>   Yeah, that's what you ***claim***.

Rude. Questioning a parent's opinion of their child probably won't be well received. The acerbic stress on *claim* emphasizes the fact that her beauty is questionable. It implies that she's actually ugly, and that the parent is lying about it. (The second person most likely hasn't seen the daughter.)

> I **know** the world is flat. God told me so!
>   It's wrong to claim that. Science has proven the word is spherical.

This will probably come across as rude, though most people wouldn't find the response insulting. But most people don't believe the world is flat, either. Here, the first party is unshakably convinced that they've been given some divine knowledge, so questioning that fact is questioning their god. To a highly religious person, that would be blasphemous, and thus rude, even though it's obvious to everyone else that they're patently wrong.

> I can take anyone in this bar! Just try me!
>   Hey man, no, don't claim that! These guys are really tough; they'll mess you up.

Most likely not rude. Even though *claim* is being used in a sharp, emphatic contradiction, the intent is to protect the first person from harm. But it might be seen as rude if the original speaker decides that the latter is suggesting he's wimpy, rather than just saying how fearsome the other men in the bar are.

Comment: Great answer. One other factor to consider is the subject. If the topic is one of pure opinion (everyone is entitled to have one), "claim" need not be insulting or mocking. Unless tone indictates otherwise, it can be a synonym for "think". For example, _"Sportscaster X claims LeBron James is the greatest basketball player of all time."_ Scornful, or not? Such a remark could be said in a snide way to disparage that opinion, or in a respectful way that implies James is a worthy candidate in the discussion, or even as a way to express shared agreement ("Well, _this expert_ agrees with me, so…").

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he will probably be offended, because by using "claim" you are insinuating that he is not being truthful or that he is deluded in some way. If you wish to remain neutral, you can use more innocuous verbs like: state, assert, say, believe, etc.

(I don't know why someone voted your question down - it's a perfectly good question.)

Comment: Not always. [Take this quote](http://www.mkgandhi.org/conflict_reso/chap09.htm): _"When Gandhi claimed that an individual's 'highest duty in life is to serve mankind and take his share in bettering its condition', he added that this could not be done unless one understands and respects the self."_ Nothing insulting or insinuating there. There may be many contexts where _claim_ can be used to express sarcasm or disbelief, but I don't think the word itself is inherently insulting. (The question was probably voted down because it needs more specific examples to be clearly answered.)

Comment: @J.R.  There's a difference between someone "claiming" a personal opinion regarding mankind as Gandhi did here, and saying that someone else "claimed" something. I believe user6612 is referring to the correct verb to use when quoting someone without insulting them.

Comment: Reading the question at face value, and your answer as you've worded it, I can see how a learner might wonder if the author of the quote insinuated that Gandhi was being insincere. (**Q**: _If I say some guy claims that something is true, would he be offended?_ **A**: _Yes, he will probably be offended, because by using "claim" you are insinuating that he is not being truthful_.) My example may be "different," as you say, but I thought that difference needed to be addressed – hence my comment.